# How to create a runnable jar file from source code programmatically?

Tags: java, jar, compilation, .class-file

I need to create  runnable `.jar` file programmatically from a string. My decision is to create a `.class` file from string and add it to the `.jar` using JarOutputStream.

1. What API must I use to create the `.class` file?
2. Are there any other solutions to create a `.jar` from the source code?

Comment: *"I need to create runnable jar programmatically from String."*  1) Why?  2) Can the end user be expected to have a JDK installed?

Comment: The compilation API. Of course there are other solutions to make a jar from source code--the normal development process. Or there are things like [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do that, you can use the [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

There is [this excellent tutorial](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/) that can walk you through.

Comment: Please could you please help me build a jar from this source code github.com/upictec/org.json.me I tried lots of things and even installed maven, but I can't get the jar

Comment: Okay so I don't know if I fully understood the process but now we compiled successfully. How can we now go to the runnable jar?

Answer (score 1):

To compile code, you need a compiler. You can either use the <del>Sun</del>Oracle compiler or the Eclipse compiler. Calling the compiler API (both have documented APIs) will produce a .class file in a temporary location. You can then make a jar.

For an example of this sort of thing, start with, for example, the [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1), which is a Java module which uses the compiler API. You'll have to find your way into the Plexus compiler module.

Comment: Please could you please help me build a jar from this source code github.com/upictec/org.json.me I tried lots of things and even installed maven, but I can't get the jar