# Programmatically creating Runnable JAR that has external JARs from a GUI?

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I have a simple test program that has one button. When a user clicks the button, the program is supposed to create a Runnable JAR. The Runnable JAR is a simple program that opens google.com in Firefox. The program has three classes.

---

**1) Main.java**

```
 package test;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Selenium.getGoogle();

        }

    }
```

---

**2) Selenium.Java**

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Selenium {

    public static void getGoogle () {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }

}
```

---

**3) TestGUI.java**

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class TestGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestGUI() {

        setSize(200, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        /*
         * JButton.
         */
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Create Runnable JAR file ! ");
        add(startButton);
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGUI();
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("The Button Works");
        String file1ToCompile = "test" + java.io.File.separator + "Main.java";

        String file2ToCompile = "test" + java.io.File.separator + "Selenium.java";

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, file1ToCompile, file2ToCompile);

        if (compilationResult == 0) {

            System.out.println("Compilation is successful");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

I have two main classes . I added `TestGUI.java` to the manifest so the GUI will show up . Once a user clicks the button, I want my program to create a Runnable JAR that consists of `Main.java` and `Selenium.java`.

However, I get an error `null pointer exception` for `int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, file1ToCompile, file2ToCompile);`

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237903/how-to-create-a-runnable-jar-file-from-source-code-programmatically

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Actually I asked this question based on the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21639695/edit

Comment: Fix your title then.  It's *exactly the same* as the other post.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Please, unmark it as if it is duplicate. I read that answer and that tutorial . I was not able to find an answer of how to deal with packaged classes and external jars that is why I ask this question

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ok, I will fix the title

Comment: Is the question about making jars from jars, or is it about the null pointer exception that you're getting at the bottom of the question?  In general, you solve null pointer exceptions by removing the condition that is causing the thing you are referencing from being null.

Comment: I guess it is about making JARs from JARs . I read the tutorial carefully and basically copy pasted the code from there . It is very simple . I have no idea why it does not work . I guess the TestGUI.java class works ONLY when we do not have any external jars like Selenium

Comment: If that line of code you pasted as the error is correct, it looks like your `compiler` variable is null.  So when you try and call `.run()` on it, it throws an exception because there is nobody home.  You need to try and bring a little more to the party; you can't really copy/paste some code from the Internet that you don't understand, and then expect us to explain to you how it works.

Comment: "Once" is how to spell "ones". I tried to edit the post to fix the typo but SO wouldn't let me because the change is "minor". Maybe so in characters, but the amount of time it takes for the brain to process what is meant rather than what is said isn't so minor, at least for someone with OCD! :)

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: NPE happens most likely because you are using a JRE instead of a JDK and `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();` returns null instead of the compiler instance.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should avoid `"test" + java.io.File.separator + "Main.java"`.  It's a bug waiting to happen.  Use `new File(new File("test"), "Main.java")`.  Or at least use System.getProperty("file.separator").

Comment: Isn't *"programmatically creating ... from a GUI"* an oxymoron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/io/createJarFile.html) is the answer O.o finally found it!! you just have to see this way the last part of the code:

```
File folder = new File("C://Users//YourUser//YourWorkspace//YourProject//bin");
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
File file=new File("C://Users//YourUser//Desktop//Examples.jar");
```

Answer (score 7):

You are getting the `NullPointerException` most likely because you are using a JRE and not a JDK. [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp) a JDK and add it to the buildpath.

Secondly, you are just compiling the files. You then need to create a jar file and add the .class files to it. it is important that they have the same package structure in the jar. In the jar you will also need:

**Manifest file**

**Dependant jars**

**Classloader**

The manifest file describes which class contains the `main` method and info on the classpath.
Dependant jars(selenium) also need to be present for obvious reasons.
a classloader is needed to load the classes in the dependant jar. below is my implementation:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("The Button Works");
        String file1ToCompile = "src" + java.io.File.separator + "test" + java.io.File.separator + "Main.java";
        String file2ToCompile = "src" + java.io.File.separator + "test" + java.io.File.separator + "Selenium.java";
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, file1ToCompile, file2ToCompile);
        if (compilationResult == 0) {
            System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
        }

        Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(new Name("Rsrc-Class-Path"), "./ selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar");
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.CLASS_PATH, ".");
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(new Name("Rsrc-Main-Class"), "test.Main");
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS, "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader");
        try{
            JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.jar"), manifest);
            add(new File("src" + java.io.File.separator + "test" + java.io.File.separator + "Main.class"), target);
            add(new File("src" + java.io.File.separator + "test" + java.io.File.separator + "Selenium.class"), target);
            add(new File("org"), target);
            add(new File("selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar"), target);
            target.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void add(File source, JarOutputStream target) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        try
        {
            if (source.isDirectory())
            {
                String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
                if (!name.isEmpty())
                {
                    if (!name.endsWith("/"))
                        name += "/";
                    JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
                    entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                    target.putNextEntry(entry);
                    target.closeEntry();
                }
                for (File nestedFile: source.listFiles())
                    add(nestedFile, target);
                return;
            }

            JarEntry entry = null;

            if(source.getPath().contains("jarinjarloader")){
                entry = new JarEntry(source.getPath());
            }
            else if(source.getName().endsWith(".class")){
                entry = new JarEntry("test/"+source.getName());
            }else if(source.getName().endsWith(".classpath")){
                entry = new JarEntry(source.getName());
            }else if(source.getName().endsWith(".jar")){
                entry = new JarEntry(source.getName());
            }
            entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
            target.putNextEntry(entry);
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                int count = in.read(buffer);
                if (count == -1)
                    break;
                target.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            target.closeEntry();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        }
    }
```

I used Eclipse's `jarinjarloader` for my classloader which I obtained by creating a runnable jar in eclipse and extracting the `org` folder and copying it into my project directory.

[image]

There is a slight problem with this but i suspect i am missing something small. output.jar will run fine if the classloader files are in the same directory as the jar. I am currently trying to fix this so that it can find the classloader from within the jar.

Comment: THis is not correct . THe answer work only from the folder . THis is not a real JAR

Comment: @CHEBURASHKA I explained that at the bottom of my answer. I am working to fix it, do you have any thoughts?